# Hashing or dictionaries for Venn diagram of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, set, union

I have two dictionaries (80K entries each) both with the same format:

```
A= {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c', '4':'d'}

B= {'2':'b', '3':'a', '4':'d', '5':'e'}
```

Some of the key:value pairs from Dict_A overlap with Dict_B.  Think of these dictionaries as Venn diagram circles.  My goal is to find the overlap of those two dictionaries and generate new Dictionaries : Dict_A, Dict_B, Dict_C, and Dict_D.
I'd like to end up with 6 total dictionaries:
where

Original dictionaries:

```
A= {'1':'a', '2':'b', '3':'c', '4':'d'}
B= {'2':'b', '3':'a', '4':'d', '5':'e'}
```

Dict_A: items with keys unique to A

```
Dict_A = {'1':'a'}
```

Dict_B: items with keys unique to B

```
Dict_B = {'5':'e'}
```

Dict_C: items with keys shared by A and B, but with values that are different

```
Dict_C = {'3':'a', '3':'c'}
```

Dict_D: items with keys AND values shared by A and B.

```
Dict_D = {'2':'b', '4':'d'}
```

I know how to find the length of these things by making them sets:

```
shared1 = set(A.items()) & set(B.items())

shared2 = set(A.keys()) & set(B.keys())
```

Then I can find out how many should be in Dict_C:
    len(shared2) - len(shared1)

But I can't figure out how to make them dictionaries.

Comment: keys need to be unique

Comment: Dict_C is not happening unless you append to a container

Comment: In addition to what @depperm said, if the set of key-value mappings remains the same across both the dictionaries, then its better to represent them as lists. At which point, you could easily use list comprehension.

Comment: Ah yes.. I had to just make two dictionaries C1 and C2, with the exact same number of items, with identical keys, and different values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since dictionary lookup time are fast (O(1), you could use dictionary comprehension:

```
>>> # use iteritems on Python2
>>> shared1 = {k: v for k, v in A.items() if i in B}
```

> Dict_A: items with keys unique to A
>
> Dict_B: items with keys unique to B

```
>>> Dict_A = {k: v for k,v in A.items() if k not in B}
>>> Dict_B = {k: v for k,v in B.items() if k not in A}
```

For your later tasks, such as:

> Dict_C: items with keys shared by A and B, but with values that are different

You can use list comprehension:

```
>>> # use iteritems for Python2
>>> # list comprehension
>>> shared1 = [k for k, v in A.items() if B.get(k) == v]
>>> # set comprehension
>>> shared1 = {k for k, v in A.items() if B.get(k) == v}
```

Remember, keys have to be unique and you only want the **keys** that differ: a list (or a set) is sufficient for this (use curly braces, or set comprehension, to generate a set).

> Dict_D: items with keys AND values shared by A and B.

Just use the same ideas as above

```
>>> Dict_D = {k: v for k, v in A.items() if B.get(k) == v}
```

Comment: This is an almost perfect answer.  I ended up making two dictionaries for Dict_C - dictC_a, and dictC_b, but it worked perfectly.  Thank you so much.  This will surely be used more and more as I use python more.